# Magento, how to route action based on user attribute

Tags: php, magento

How can I change/reroute the currently requested action if the user isn't logged in.

This is for my custom module's controller.

Did think of overriding preDispatch() but don't think this is correct.

Something like,

```
init() {
    if (!$user->loggedIn)
       change action
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->_redirect($path, $arguments=array());
```

For more info see http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-redirect-functions/